# como ejecutar alguna acción cada 10 segundos

Tags: java, hilos

Quisiera saber como ejecutar alguna acción cada 10 segundos, especificamente llamar desde el `main` a mi método `msj()` cada 10 segundos utilizando la clase `Thread` y también quisiera saber como se haría utilizando la interfaz `Runnable`.

```
package javaapplication1;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public void msj() {
        System.out.println("hola");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

te recomiendo leer un poco de la clase Thread, ver y realizar ejemplos para poder adaptar funcionamiento acorde a tus necesidades, respondiendo a tu pregunta, la manera recomendada para llamar un metodo cada x tiempo, a partir de Java 5 es con un **ScheduledExecutorService**, lo creas usando la clase **Executors**.

```
public class RunClass {
    final Runnable tarea = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            hola_mundo();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RunClass on = new RunClass();
        ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors
                .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(on.tarea, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    void hola_mundo() {
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
    }
}
```

Documentación:

[ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1):

El uso de un objecto de la interfaz [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) es definitivamente el camino a seguir... pero si esto se trata de un ejercicio meramente **didáctico**, entonces:

#### ❏ [`java.lang.Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Una solución usando **únicamente** la clase [`java.lang.Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) podría ser similar a la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                msj();
            }
        }.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void msj() {
    System.out.println("hola");
}
```

#### ❏ [`java.lang.Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)

La cosa cambia con [`java.lang.Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), porque no hay una solución que use únicamente esa clase, ya que se requiere que *algo* ejecute la tarea. Por ejemplo, con [`java.lang.Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                msj();
            }
        }).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void msj() {
    System.out.println("hola");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package javaapplication1;


   public class JavaApplication1 extends Thread {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaApplication1 hilo= new JavaApplication1 ();
     hilo.start();
    }

    public void run(){
    while(true  ){
    try{
    msj();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    }catch( InterruptedException e){}

    }
    }

   public void msj()
    {
        System.out.println("hola");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba con el siguiente fragmento de codigo :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class JavaApplication1 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    tareaProgramada();
}

public static void msj()
{
    System.out.println("hola");
}

public static void tareaProgramada()
{
    //Debemos obtener una instancia de la Interfaz ScheduledExecutorService
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    //luego debemos crear una instancia de la interfaz Runnable, tambien puede ser Callable en la cual indicamos el metodo que vamos a ejecutar
    Runnable tarea = () -> msj();
    //finalmente ordenamos ejecutar la tarea programada con un intervalo llamando al metodo scheduleWithFixedDelay el cual recibe una instancia de Runnable o Callable
    //ademas de dos int , el primero especificando cuanto tiempo esperar para ejecutar la primera tarea ,el segundo el intervalo que se esperara para continuar la siguiente ejecucion
    //el ultimo parametro es un TimeUnit el cual especifica la unidad tiempo con la que se trabajara
    service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(tarea, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }
}
```

Documentacion de la API de Concurrencia de Java : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html